# How to get distance of each repeated word in python list?

Tags: python, list

```
A = ['dcv', 'asc', 'dfg','lku','drf','asd','dcv','tfd','cfv','asc','dds','ast','lku']
'dcv': 6
'asc': 8
'lku': 9
```

What I want to know is the distance between repeated words in Python syntax, divided into regular intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a dict to store the indices of the values when you encounter them while iterating. If a value has already been seen, print the distance:

```
A = ['dcv', 'asc', 'dfg','lku','drf','asd','dcv','tfd','cfv','asc','dds','ast','lku']

d = {}
for idx, value in enumerate(A):
    if value in d:
        print(f'{value}: {idx - d[value]}')
    d[value] = idx
```

Output:

```
dcv: 6
asc: 8
lku: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will tell you index of similar word present in the list.

```
A = ['dcv', 'asc', 'dfg','lku','drf','asd','dcv','tfd','cfv','asc','dds','ast','lku']

d = {}
for i, word in enumerate(A):
    if word in d:
        print(f'{word}: {i - d[word]}')
    d[word] = i
```

Comment: This answers most of the question, but this is really inefficient, as it is about O(n^2), while it can be done in O(n).

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I am not aware of O(n^2) or O(n). Can you please provide any reference for me to learn. Thank you.

Comment: The above result emits:
lku [3, 12],
Distance between repeated words are : 9,
dcv [0, 6] ....     like this. I'm a little confused. I don't know what the result means. Can I get a more neat result like I said?

Comment: You have two imbricated loops, who will run a total times of (number of different words) * (length of the initial list), which is approximately the square of the size of the data. So, if the data gets 10 times larger, the time needed to treat it will be about 100 times larger. I added an answer showing a way to do it with only one iteration on the data, so the number of operations is proportional to its size.

Comment: ohh.. I had made it complicated. It was so  simple. Thank you:)